# Problemas em ativa o Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, mustache.js

Veja abaixo a estrutura do meu pequeno projeto;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="hello">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>{ { msg } }</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse é meu arquivo js com o nome de app.js

```
var hello = new vue({
    el:'#hello',
    data:{
        msg: "Hello Vue"
    }
});
```

Era para aparecer assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém aparece assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que será que está acontecendo isso?

Comment: Testa com as chavetas junto uma à outra, sem espaços:  `<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>`

Comment: pegou, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [compilador de templates do Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) usa a sintaxe [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) e portanto precisa que as chavetas `{{` e `}}` estejam lado a lado, sem espaços. Essa é sintaxe correta.

Muda então para:

```
<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
```